# JDK11 Upgrade Fails - ClassNotFoundException jdk.internal.ref.Cleaner

Tags: java, jboss, java-11, java-ee-6

I have upgraded my Java EE application to JDK 11 from JDK 8. But when I'm deploying into the JBOSS EAP 7.3 server I get the following exception.

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: jdk.internal.ref.Cleaner from [Module "deployment.DFNNTPOMS_X_X_3.003.000.00.0.ear" from Service Module Loader]
    at deployment.DFNNTPOMS_X_X_3.003.000.00.0.ear//net.openhft.chronicle.hash.impl.util.CleanerUtils.<clinit>(CleanerUtils.java:42)
    ... 63 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: jdk.internal.ref.Cleaner from [Module "deployment.DFNNTPOMS_X_X_3.003.000.00.0.ear" from Service Module Loader]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:198)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:412)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:400)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:116)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:315)
    at deployment.DFNNTPOMS_X_X_3.003.000.00.0.ear//net.openhft.chronicle.hash.impl.util.CleanerUtils.<clinit>(CleanerUtils.java:35)
    ... 63 more
```

Any solution ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code should use [`java.lang.ref.Cleaner`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ref/Cleaner.html) instead of `jdk.internal.ref.Cleaner`.  The latter was removed in Java 9:

- https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8149925

If the usage of the "internal" `Cleaner` class is actually coming from 3rd-party library code, then you need to upgrade the library to a Java 11 compatible version.

Comment: This is really helpful. I'm using chronicle-map latest version but it uses "jdk.internal.ref.Cleaner" which caused me the problem

Comment: According to this document (https://chronicle.software/chronicle-support-java-17/) chronicle-map they have supported JDK 11. Can exporting (-add-exports=java.base/jdk.internal.ref=ALL-UNNAMED) solve this issue ? Since this is class not found exception

Comment: I don't know.  Try it and see.  But it seriously *sucks* that Chronicle have not fixed this properly.  They have had **years** to do it.

Comment: Framework authors seem to have an obsession with using internal APIs. When I look at [this source code](https://github.com/OpenHFT/Chronicle-Map/blob/23597364ba9b6c48055ba5fdbb5403d64d9f5dc1/src/main/java/net/openhft/chronicle/hash/impl/util/CleanerUtils.java#L33), I see, they added a branch for JDK 9+. But instead of saying “at last, we have an official API, `java.lang.ref.Cleaner`, we can use”, they were like, “hey, I found there’s still an internal unofficial thing we can hack into”. But if this ever worked, it indicates that the class wasn’t really removed, contrary to the bug report.